# why are all if statements NOT Executed in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

This is a part of the program i am writing for a transport system. the scenario is that a journey has three stages: Stage 1 will pick passenger from home and drop at the station. Stage 2 will take passenger from departure station to arrival station. Stage 3 will take passenger from arrival station to the actual destination they want to go to. Each stage has a price and corresponding code which the passenger has to enter when booking a journey. Finally total price has to be calculated for the journey.The relevant code is shown below.

I created 3 lists to store those codes with their prices and take input of the codes from the passenger. I thought that using a for loop to iterate over each item in list I can just compare it against the input by user and then get the corresponding price. But this code does not do what i think it should do. I am going to guess i made a very silly mistake but i just cant figure it out.

What i want from this code is the correct price. but it does not give the correct price. E.g: if i choose 'C1','M1','F1' as input the price should total to 8.75 but it outputs 1.5 instead.

```
journeyStageOne = [['C1',1.50],['C2',3.00],['C3',4.50],['C4',6.00],['C5',8.00]]
journeyStageTwo = [['M1',5.75],['M2',12.50],['M3',22.25],['M4',34.50],['M5',45.00]]
journeyStageThree = [['F1',1.50],['F2',3.00],['F3',4.50],['F4',6.00],['F5',8.00]]

code1 = input('Enter code for stage 1 of journey: ')
code2 = input('Enter code for stage 2 of journey: ')
code3 = input('Enter code for stage 3 of journey: ')

total = 0
price1 = 0
price2 = 0
price3 = 0

for count in range(5):

    if journeyStageOne[count][0] == code1.upper():
        price1 = journeyStageOne[count][1]
        print('one')

    if journeyStageTwo[count][0] == code2.upper():
        price2 = journeyStageTwo[count][1]
        print('two')

    if journeyStageThree[count][0] == code3.upper():
        price3 = journeyStageThree[count][1]
        print('three')

total = price1+price2+price3
print(total)
```

*Those print statements inside for loop were used just to check until where the code executes and it only does so until the first if block. Why?

If my approach is wrong please do tell me what i should write instead of all this.

Comment: You have two blocks with `journeyStageTwo` - is that intentional or copy-paste error?

Comment: i wrote it wrong, thanks for showing me.

Answer (score 1):

The only change in your code in the third if loop, you wrote

```
journeyStageTwo[count][0]
```

instead of

```
journeyStageThree[count][0]
```

That's the resaon you are getting wrong output, I hope you will correct it